# How do you prevent Hudson from deleting the source tree after a build?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I have several projects that I check out from SVN, some have to be built by ant before the others. I've assigned each project to a job. 
proj A
proj B

In order for B to build, A has to be already built. So, how do tell hudson to not delete A after it checks it out and build it?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't remove the build, unless you are a bit too severe on the "Discard Old Build" settings:

[image]